# How to have same alias for two column in select in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I want to create view or table from this select:

```
Select '12' a, '13' a
From dual;
```

When I run it alone without create, it's ok and works but when I put

```
create or replace view_1
As
Select '12' a, '13' b
From dual;
```

It has error:

> duplicate column name

Comment: Create or replace view view_1 as select '12' a,'13' a from dual;       ??

Comment: Did you mean the `create or replace view` doesn't work if you assign the same alias? In the example you gave DIFFERENT aliases (`a` and `b`), which should work - there is no duplicate column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply write a `SELECT` query, you can give the same "name" (alias) to two columns, because the `SELECT` statement is self-contained and "final" (it is not used in any further processing). Still odd - why would you want two columns with the same name - but you can do it.

You CAN'T do this for a table, a view, or a subquery. In all cases, you should be able to do further processing (specifically further `SELECT`) on the result, and now the fact that two columns have the same name becomes a fatal defect. So Oracle, obviously, doesn't let you do it. If it allows you two columns with the same name in the view, and then you select `a` from the view, which `a` should be selected?

Why do you want to use the same name for two columns? Or were you just playing around and trying to understand what is going on (and in particular why the different behavior)? I hope it's the latter, and I hope you now understand why.

Comment: Thanks ,I created a table that have for example two column ,c_1 and c_2  after that inserted first row with name of columns,for example A and A,then inserted values of two column in my table, because I wanna export of result of table,I could it and have a table with two columns that have same names.

Comment: I wanna export from table to excel .:)

Comment: Why do you want two columns with the same name in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Aliases (column names) must be unique within the view.
Refer to the documentation: [CREATE VIEW](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504)

> **alias**
>
> Specify names for the expressions selected by the defining query of
>   the view. The number of aliases must match the number of expressions
>   selected by the view. Aliases must follow the rules for naming Oracle
>   Database schema objects. **Aliases must be unique within the view.**
>
> **If you omit the aliases, then the database derives them from the
>   columns or column aliases in the query.** For this reason, you must use
>   aliases if the query contains expressions rather than only column
>   names. Also, you must specify aliases if the view definition includes
>   constraints.

Comment: I needed this output for input in excel .therefore must made a select function that have some columns with same alias names.

Comment: You right ,in create view we can't have same column names,then I had to made it with this solution.      Thanks a lot.